# Integer division acting strangely

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using the following code in xCode, to work out how much to initially zoom on a UIImage in a scroll view but it keeps returning zero.

```
int heightRatio = self.scrollView.bounds.size.height / self.imageView.image.size.height;
```

The strange thing is if I do a subtraction it works, just not with division.

XCode describes both height variables as a "GLuint", some graphics version of int I think.

I've NSLogged both numbers on the right, and neither are zero.

I've tried defining heightRatio as a GLuint as well, with no joy, and also converting to NSNumber but it's all just getting a bit messy.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: They're not `GLuint`s, they're `CGFloat`s. `bounds` is a `CGRect` and `bounds.size` is a `CGSize` which contains 2 `CGFloat`s, width & height. Not sure why it's zero though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare `heightRatio` as a `double` (and round later if you want to have an `int`).

Answer (score 1):

Both `self.scrollView.bounds.size.height` and `self.imageView.image.size.height` are of type `CGFloat`. If you declare `heightRatio` as `CGFloat` as well, you would correctly capture division results between 0 and 1. If you need to make it an integer later, use `ceil()`, `trunc()`, or `round()` to round up, down, or to the nearest whole number.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but double may not be enough, the only way to make division without lose data is using NSDecimal number. Here a sample code, show the percentage of working in a loop

```
NSDecimalNumber *Percentuale = [[[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",ClienteNr]] decimalNumberByDividingBy:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[[Globals ClientiDaMostrareMappa] count]]]] decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100"]];
    [Globals.WaitAlert setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Localizzazione Clienti!\nAttendere...  %i%%",[Percentuale intValue]]];
```